# Different fonts in URXVT for users on the same computer

Tags: linux, fonts, urxvt

Two different desktop users on the same machine with the same fonts and the same xrdb are getting different fonts in URXVT, and one of them looks horrible. I have no idea what could be causing the difference. Compare:

[image: Weird font]

to

[image: Expected font]

So the question is, what could be causing this, and what tools could I use to diagnose the problem?

(Debian Jessie, if it's relevant)

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like if the Characters on the first  Picture are rasterized (Raster Font) and the one on the second are subpixeled (ClearType Font).

Maybe there is a different default font set in the URXVT Settings it selfs it may also be Caused by a different default Font setting in the OS itself.

Hope it helps

Comment: Far as I can tell, URXVT claims that it's using the same font in both instances (I could be mistaken). It also has the same kind of problem if I manually change fonts.

Comment: it may also be a userdependent setting of compiz which is able to apply anti-aliasing to windows in general. i would recommend you to check if compiz is installed if yes - then have a look at the compiz settings of both users